# Cannot delete some custom user certificates on Android 10

Tags: android-10, certificates, samsung-galaxy-note-9

I have added user certificates, but Android do not let me delete most of them.

How did I add the certificates:

- Open the setting drop down menu
- Go to *Biometrics and Security* -> *Other Security settings* -> *Install from Device Storage*
- Enter the pin
- Type a name for the certificate
- Choose if it is used for *VPN and apps* or *Wi-Fi*

1- If I add it as a *Wi-Fi* cert, then I can see it in the list from the *User certificates* menu, but it is not present in the list from *View Security* certificates. This kind of certificate do not let me delete the certificate later.

2- If I add it as a *VPN and apps* cert, then I see it both in the list from the *User certificates* menu, and also in the list from the menu *View security certificates*, at the tab `USER`. Only from this tab I can delete the certificate. I cannot delete from the menu *User certificates*.

In both scenarios the CA certificate has no effect. The certificate has been tested in other different machines, working fine, and it has the flag *CA=TRUE*.

Then, my questions are:

a- How to delete the *VPN and apps* certificates I've ended up adding many duplicates

b- How to get the CA certificate to properly work? I am testing it with Firefox, Firefox Focus, and Chrome.

*Android version 10, running on Samsung Galaxy note 9.*